# Manual transmission SUV towed in neutral with parking brake on

Tags: brakes, towing

Trying to assess the damage to a vehicle of mine from being towed. Vehicle isn't currently insured (project truck/won't start), so not able to test drive it at the moment.

Vehicle was towed about 20km (12 miles) in neutral, but the parking brake was NOT dis-engaged. What is the extent of the damage that could have been caused? From my research, I am assuming I'll have damage to the wheels, and e-brake shoes. Anything else I should be looking for?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Your e-brake shoes are toast and possibly the rotor/drum is also, but I wouldn't expect any damage beyond that. The e-brake shoes would probably give up before they got hot enough to ruin anything else. It depends somewhat if your SUV has separate e-brake shoes or not, the separate shoes would be smaller and less capable of transferring lots of heat/doing damage.

Comment: I wouldn't think there's any damage to the wheels.

Comment: @masospaghetti Thanks for the info. It's a 2000 Nissan Xterra. I'll have to do some research on whether it has seperate e-brake shoes. Definitely smelt the brakes when I arrived at the vehicle... was not very happy. (There was a miscommunication between me and the driver about whether one of us had disengaged the parking brake, wasn't entirely his fault, but also wasn't mine. It's is his responsibility to ensure it is removed.)